# Changing the default date format in classic asp when using the "date" function

Tags: date, asp-classic

I'm migrating a whole bunch of web pages that were written in classic asp over to a new server, and have discovered many references to the simple *date()* function, like:

```
    if cint(left(date,instr(date,"/")-1)) < 9 then blah blah
```

I'm getting errors because the new server's default date format is returning *yyyy-mm-dd*, and the code above is expecting it to be in *dd/mm/yyyy* format.

Rather than manually fixing every occurrence, of which there could be hundreds, I'm looking to see if I can change the default date format for asp so that *date()* returns *dd/mm/yyyy*. I thought by simply changing the system's short date format would do the trick, but even after restarting the server it's still showing *yyyy-mm-dd*.

Is there a setting somewhere where you can specify the *default* date format when using the *date()* function?

Comment: VBScript *(and by extension Classic ASP)* uses the system locale when displaying datetime values. To modify this, change the Regional Settings of the Server through the Windows Server Control Panel.

Comment: If you don't have access to your server desktop you can use the Locale ID (lcid) property in the directive at the start of the page, eg `<%@Language="vbscript" LCID="2057"%>` would set UK date format (and UK currency format) for the page.  More info here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525091(v=vs.90).aspx, and a list of Locale Id values here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912047(v=winembedded.10).aspx

Comment: I know it doesn't help when you have hundreds of pages to fix, but there are functions for getting specific parts of a date: `Month(date)`, `Day(date)`, `Year(date)`, and if none of those will serve, there's `DatePart(interval,date)`. So if there are pages which you're gonna have to edit anyway, you could replace the fragile and unnecessary string parsing with functions that'll work regardless of the date format.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Although I discovered _LCID_ shortly after posting the question, in the end I ended up changing the regional settings of the server from _English - Canada_ to _English - United States_, which did the trick. So changing just the _short date format_ in regional settings wasn't enough.

Comment: Even after the fix, I still found some instances where I wasn't getting the date format I wanted, so I added the `Session.LCID=1033` in the _Session_OnStart_ Sub to the _global.asa_ file to force it. I _think_ that did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:
change global.asa, in the Sub Session_OnStart, add a line

```
Session.LCID=1033
```